# Jersey web app in Karaf OSGI environment does not work

Tags: java, osgi, jersey-2.0, karaf

I installed and activated the jersey server 2.19 bundles (and dependencies) in Apache Karaf in order to create a simple webapp ( /tracks/get which produce a json representation of a Track object with simple name and artist fields).

I created a bundle version of my war file and installed it in Karaf.

When I start the war bundle I get the following exception:

```
2016-10-14 10:35:08,299 | DEBUG | pool-4-thread-1  | FactoryFinder                    | 84 - javax.ws.rs-api - 2.0.1 | Unable to load provider class org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl using custom classloader org.ops4j.pax.web.service.spi.util.ResourceDelegatingBundleClassLoader trying again with current classloader.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)[org.eclipse.osgi-3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar:]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)[org.eclipse.osgi-3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar:]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)[org.eclipse.osgi-3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar:]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)[:1.7.0_21]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)[org.eclipse.osgi-3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar:]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleClassLoader.java:176)[60:org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)[:1.7.0_21]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleClassLoader.java:192)[60:org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)[:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)[:1.7.0_21]
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:107)[84:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1]
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:166)[84:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1]
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:135)[84:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1]
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:120)[84:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1]
    at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:179)[84:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.extractMediaTypes(IntrospectionModeller.java:280)[102:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.19.0]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.extractMediaTypes(IntrospectionModeller.java:269)[102:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.19.0]
```

which I presume is the reason why my webapp does not work.

It seems that jersey is inspecting my annotated service class and at some point it needs a RuntimeDelegateImpl instance. This code is from the org.glassfish.jersey.server bundle. 
The RuntimeDelegateImpl class is instantiated via Class.forName().newInstance() in code from the javax.ws.rs.ext bundle. 
The root problem is that the javax.ws bundle's classloader does not find the org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl in the classpath. But I don't understand how that is, since that class is part of the org.glassfish.jersey.server bundle which is activated and Export-Package: has that package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by registering my Jersey Application directly into the osgi http service.

Comment: can you provide an example how you did that ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if jersey works out of the box in karaf. The typical way to do REST in karaf is to use Apache CXF. CXF offers blueprint namespaces for REST as well as [CXF-DOSGi which can export REST endpoints](https://github.com/apache/cxf-dosgi/tree/master/samples/rest) based on exported OSGi services.

If you want to use jersey then there is the [osgi-jaxrs-connector](https://github.com/hstaudacher/osgi-jax-rs-connector/).
Which does a similar thing as CXF-DOSGi.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For the time being we need to use Jersey.